# ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, viewbag

I met the trouble when i used ViewBag to pass data to View.
I had a Model with name: "Place". It contains {PlaceId, Name, Description, National, Area, Provience, MapKey}

In an action in a controller. I need to take {PlaceId, Name} of "Place" Model to pass to a select-option. Here is my code:

- In controller:

  ```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      var place = from p in db.Places
                     select new { p.PlaceId, p.Name};
      ViewBag.list = place.ToList();
      return View();
  }
  ```

+In view:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="Place" name="PlaceId" title="Chose a place">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.list)
                {
                    <option value="@item.PlaceId">@item.Name</option>
                }
    </select>
```

I met error here. This error is: ***'object' does not contain a definition for 'PlaceId'***

Comment: Your passing a collection of anonymous objects. Forget this and do it the right way - in the controller - `ViewBag.list = new SelectList(db.Places, "PlaceId", "Name");` and in the view - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.list)`

Comment: [This article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) will help to explain why you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you passing a collection of anonymous objects to the view. [This article](http://www.gregshackles.com/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/) explains the issue in detail, but to paraphrase

> Anonymous objects are internal by default, meaning they are only accessible to the assembly in which they were created. Once you cross that assembly boundary, it gets treated as a regular object, which does not have the `PlaceId` property

Th correct approach is to assign the collection to a `SelectList` (or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) property in a view model, or to `ViewBag`.

For example, using a view model

```
public SelectList PlacesList { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
model.PlacesList = new SelectList(db.Places, "PlaceId", "Name");
```

and then in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.yourProperty, Model.PlacesList)
```